# How to update dataframe with another unaligned preferring the NaNs from the second without hack

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['update me', 'leave', 'take the other nan']], index=[0], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['update with me', pd.np.nan, 'stay out']], index=[0], columns=['A', 'C', 'D'])

# want something like: df1.update_using_nans_please(df2) # to return:
# pd.DataFrame([['update with me', 'leave', pd.np.nan]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
df1.update(df2.fillna('nan'))
df1.replace('nan', pd.np.nan)  # Any way to do it without this hack?
```

Apologies for the brevity, but I'm wondering if there's a more elegant way than the fillna/replace hack above?

Comment: actual output vs desired output would help a lot!

Comment: I don't think so, at least not without anything simpler than the `.fillna` + `replace` you currently have. The issue is that `.update` is used to specifiically "Modify in place using **non-NA** values from another DataFrame" and this behavior doesn't seem to be modifiable.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the fact that pandas does not favour replacing non-NaNs with NaNs, only the other way around, your method isn't that bad.

However, as an alternative, we can use a little indexing magic with `pd.concat`. This does not perform in-place modification, however, for the reason above.

```
a, b = df1.columns, df2.columns
pd.concat([df1[a.difference(b)], df2[a.intersection(b)]], axis=1)

       B               A   C
0  leave  update with me NaN
```

---

To retain the original ordering,

```
pd.concat([df1[a.difference(b)], df2[a.intersection(b)]], axis=1).reindex_like(df1)

                A      B   C
0  update with me  leave NaN
```